# OpenLDAP telephoneNumber schema

Tags: ldap, openldap

I try to create a phonebook with OpenLDAP 2.4.31 with the standard schemas.

Inserting a number containing a hash (#) or asterisk (*) won't work and return me a syntax error.

RFCs tell me that a number is the following: Printable string (alphabetic, digits, ', (, ), +, ,, -, ., /, :, ?, and space) and "

How can I edit the schema to support # and * characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are having the same exact issue! Mobile networks offer a variety of services and information accessed using numbers that include either pound (hash) or star. Its a perfectly valid question for perfectly normal use of a phone number field.

Having a very casual look at RFC 4517, I see that it's really true! The LDAP RFC offers only a very limited selection of basic syntax types, and telephoneNumber maps to PrintableString. Probably a case of the RFCWG more interested in their RFC for its own sake, than the practical application thereof. I mean, which would be more useful in a phone number field - '?' or '#'..

As was already alluded, hacking cosine.schema can lead to even larger problems and is not upgrade-safe. FYI there are a few LDAP servers out there, many a bit more flexible about the RFC implementation. Have a look at OpenDJ:
https://forgerock.org/opendj/

*Any* server-side 'fix' in this case will likely no longer be strictly RFC compliant, which runs the risk of your original syntax issues revisiting you, if you  ever need to exchange LDIF with *other* LDAP systems. But IMHO changing the client mapping to another unrelated field type could hardly be called 'better', especially from an onlooker's perspective. So either get another LDAP server which is more forgiving or change the field mapping on the client - *either* way presents risks and should be understood as a limitation of RFC 4517.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change the OID in the `telephoneNumber` schema entry to refer to a more general attribute syntax OID as per the RFCs. Not a good idea. You would be better off using a different attribute.

Comment: I can't use a different attribute, because I have phones searching with those attributes. Had the same idea of changing the OID - is it sufficent to change the syntax in the core, or do I have to do more steps?